# Ionic 3: In App Browser on Background ‘Active resource loading counts reached to a per-frame limit’

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing a application with Ionic 3 and i have some processes that need to be done in a in-app-browser and aesthetically was not pleasant to the user so i decided to hide it in the background and place a modal in front . And in IOS everything works perfectly, but on android doing the same processes i get the following error.

Active resource loading counts reached to a per-frame limit while the tab is in background. Network requests will be delayed until a previous loading finishes, or the tab is foregrounded. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5527160148197376 for more details

After clicking the link of ‘chromestatus’ it has a paragraph saying ‘Thus, all requests will run eventually.’

but in my case the app just hangs and never does the requests. Someone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe you need to regulate the number of requests that are fired at the same time by making sure that not more that five are being fetched at a time. Maybe this error on Chromium (android) stops the execution of your code

Comment: Indeed this error stopped the execution of the code. But i believe it was fixed on chromium side as well. From my side i also made no concurrent requests, just one at the time and it fixed maybe 70% of the cases, the other 30% were fixed randomly which made me believe was also a bug in chromium side